# TypeError: sequelize.sync is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Help! I keep getting this error when I run 'npm start'

```
TypeError: sequelize.sync is not a function
```

Here is the code for my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes')
// Import Sequelize Connection
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(routes);

// Sync sequelize models to the database, then turn on the server
sequelize.sync({ force: true, alter: true }).then (() => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => 
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`));
});
```

and

```
require('dotenv').config();

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = process.env.JAWSDB_URL
  ? new Sequelize(process.env.JAWSDB_URL)
  : new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PW, {
      host: 'localhost',
      dialect: 'mysql',
      dialectOptions: {
        decimalNumbers: true,
      },
    });

module.exports = sequelize;
```

All my dependencies are installed, not really sure what else I can do. I've deleted my package-lock.json & node modules and did a cache clean with no success.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the database connection part, you can find infos [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html).

You need to get an instance of sequelize that is connected to your actual database, and to do so, you will need to get the url of connection. There are a few free postgresql database around

What you need to add is something like this :

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/dbname')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the force option like this:

```js
sequelize.sync({
    force: true
});
```